# Clear a Section of Field values on ReRender in visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am currently working on a requirement which requires me to render a section of fields depending on the value in a check box(i.e when the box is checked). That part has been completed now. But the problem is when i enter some values in the fields and then undo and recheck the box the values need to be refreshed to default values. Is there any way this can be done?
If so can it be done only in visualforce page or will i need to have a apex class do it for me?

Thanks and regards

Comment: There is also a Salesforce-specific Stack overflow community.  If you don't get an answer that works for you here, consider trying there too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Visualforce code I use to do something similar:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
Use primary guardian as 1st emergency contact:
<apex:inputCheckbox id="SamePGEC" value="{!SamePGEC}">
<apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="InputSec" />
</apex:inputCheckbox>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Note how checking/unchecking the checkbox makes a call to the setter function SamePGEC in the controller.  Note also the "rerender" attribute that causes the InputSec panel to get refreshed.

For me, SamePGEC looks like this:

```
public Boolean SamePGEC{get;set;}
```

but you could expand the simple accessor function into a actual function that updates the variables you need restored to default values

Comment: Thanks will check on this solution... I was trying to directly render and remove the fields without an apex class.

Comment: I'm sure this could be done with Javascript too.  Perhaps someone else will jump in and show us how that alternative works.